# Website backend suggestion

Tags: python, html, css, database, web

I am planning to launch a website. i have knowledge of HTML and CSS. But i want to add some back end with database in my site.

User will register and save some details.

So need to update in database and retrieve by the user.

I have designed my site with HTML and CSS. even i bought domain name.

Now i do not know how to proceed with this back end things.

People are suggesting me to go with Python.

I need some help here in how to proceed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: @Paulie_D  I can't ask suggestions here?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a loaded question with no singular answer. If you go with Python I would suggest using Django. Django is a useful web framwork which has many useful features such as scaffolding generation that makes rapid web development easier. Additionally, Django is geared towards MVC style web development which I prefer and provides easy database interaction. When I learned Django I followed [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/) tutorial. From there I used heroku to deploy my Django app, heroku allows for easy deployment of web applications making use of git repositories and can be found [here](https://www.heroku.com/). heroku provides many seful tools for free such as custom urls, and database access. One tip, if you use django and heroku, use postgres for the database as that is the database used by heroku